# Magento 2 add category url in all products, frontend

Tags: magento2, category, url, products

I want to display all product url in frontend with category name inside, I had checked all the configuration, but didn't find anything.
Now I think I have to do it by coding, please guide me little bit how to start?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, as I checked there is no configuration. I recheked and found one configuration
and it fixed the issue.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Create your extension and Overwrite product list page, product details page. after that create block and call below function were you want category url.

```
nameSpace ['Your_nameSpace'] 
use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
class ['Your_Class_name']
    protected $_registry;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
    ) {
        .........

        $this->_registry = $registry;
    }

     public  function getCategory()
    {
            $current_category = $this->_registry->registry('current_category');


            return $current_category->getUrl();


    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for comment. I will try it asswell.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a function in helper and call in the phtml file where you want to show.

```
public function getProductCategoryName($product)
{
    $html = '';
    $categories = $product->getCategoryIds(); /*will return category ids array*/
    foreach($categories as $category){

        $cat = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->load($category);

        $html.= "<span class='product-category'>";
        $html.= $cat->getName();
        $html.= '</span>';

    }
    return $html;
}
```

Suppose product assigned in multiple category. In phtml file, you can call below code:

```
<?php
   echo $helper->getProductCategoryName($product);
 ?>
```

Hope this can help.

Comment: Thankyou for comment. I will try it asswell.